# TFS - Sync server to local manually

Tags: tfs

**Task**: A fresh fetch of TFS branch source takes 12+ hours to download due to latency on the VPN (everyone working from home). A in office local fetch takes 7 minutes to a SSD drive.
If we manually ZIP the files via an office VM and upload to home, an unzip, this can happen in less than 30m. We use an on premise TFS 2019 server.

**Problem**: Visual Studio shows "not downloaded" and requires a fresh fetch. I want to be able to tell TFS manually that the server and local copy is in SYNC... I did some research and came up empty.
I looked at the "reconcile" tf option but that just then wants to download the files.

So does anyone know a magic way to keep Visual Studio happy to show
Latest" Yes ?

03-Nov NB: My context was TFVC

Answer (score 0):

> TFS - Sync server to local manually

You could create a new folder to connect the repo, and we do not have to wait until the clone is completed (it will take you a long time), you can choose to cancel:

[image]

Then delete the files in the new folder.

Next, copy the latest repo folder from your office VM, then add files to the new folder.

Close your Visual Studio and re-open it, make any change in the projects, then we could sync it to the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My case is TFVC, i am guessing your answer is GIT related . Because i dont use GIT, i had not considered making this clear.